# ORA-01722: invalid number when creating materialized view

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, materialized-views

I am creating a view and the same view converted into materialized view in the same system. But doing the same thing in another system I got error `ORA-01722: invalid number` when creating the materialized view. Why?

```
create materialized view MV_EMP_VALI 
 refresh complete with rowid start with SYSDATE+1/24 AS 
 (select * from V_CHA1);
```

View:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_CHA1 AS(SELECT EMPNO,
       MONTHYEAR,
       to_number(SUM(CPFEMO)) AS EMOLUMENTS,
       to_number(SUM(CPEPF)) AS EMPPFSTATUARY,
       to_number(SUM(AEMO)) AS AEMO,
       to_number(SUM(APEPF)) AS APEPF,
       MAX(recsts) AS recsts
  FROM ((SELECT RECDATE,
                   (CASE WHEN (REPFEMOFLAG='N') THEN
                round(NVL(trim(EMO), 0))
                ELSE
                round(NVL(REVISEMO, 0)) END ) as CPFEMO,
                round(NVL(trim(EPF), 0)) AS CPEPF,
                0 as AEMO,
                0 as APEPF,
                '' as recsts,
                EMPNO
           FROM EMP_VALI
          WHERE EFLAG = 'Y' AND SFLAG = 'N' AND EMPNO IS NOT NULL and
                RECDATE >'01-Apr-2011')
        union all
        (SELECT NDT.RECDATE AS RECDATE,
                sum(round(NVL(trim(NDT.EMO), 0))) as CPFEMO,
                sum(round(NVL(trim(NDT.EPF), 0))) as CPEPF,
                0 as AEMO,
                0 AS APEPF,
                NDT.EMPNO
           FROM EMP_VALI VAL, EMP_SUPP NDT
          WHERE VAL.EMPNO = NDT.EMPNO AND VAL.EFLAG = NDT.EFLAG AND
                VAL.EFLAG = 'Y' AND VAL.SFLAG = 'Y' AND
                NDT.SLIFLAG='N' and
                 VAL.EMPNO is not null and
                NDT.RECDATE = VAL.RECDATE
           GROUP BY NDT.RECDATE, NDT.EMPNO) UNION ALL
        (SELECT DT.RECPAIDDATE AS RECDATE,
                0           as CPFEMO,
                0           as CPEPF,
                sum(round(NVL(trim(DT.EMO), 0))) as AEMO,
                sum(round(NVL(trim(DT.EPF), 0))) AS APEPF,
        max('') as recsts,
                DT.EMPNO
           FROM EMP_VALI VAL, EMP_SUPP DT
          WHERE VAL.EMPNO = DT.EMPNO AND VAL.EFLAG = DT.EFLAG AND
                VAL.EFLAG = 'Y' AND VAL.SFLAG = 'Y'  AND
                VAL.EMPNO IS NOT NULL and dt.RECDATE=val.RECDATE AND DT.SFLAG IS NOT NULL AND DT.SFLAG not in ('N','F')
           GROUP BY DT.RECPAIDDATE, DT.EMPNO)UNION ALL
        (SELECT DT.RECPAIDDATE AS RECDATE,
      SUM((CASE
             WHEN (DT.ECR4FLAG = 'C') then
              round(NVL(trim(DT.EMO), 0))
             else
             0
           end)) as CPFEMO,
       sum((CASE
             WHEN DT.ECR4FLAG = 'C' then
              round(NVL(trim(DT.EPF), 0))
             else
              0
           end)) as CPEPF,
          sum((CASE
             WHEN DT.ECR4FLAG = 'A' then
              round(NVL(trim(DT.EMO), 0))
             else
              0
           end)) as AEMO,
       sum((CASE
             WHEN DT.ECR4FLAG = 'A' then
              round(NVL(trim(DT.EPF), 0))
             else
              0
           end)) as APEPF,
       max(EMPRECOVERYSTS) as recsts,
       DT.EMPNO
  FROM EMP_VALI VAL, EMP_SUPP DT
WHERE VAL.EMPNO = DT.EMPNO AND VAL.EFLAG = DT.EFLAG AND
       VAL.EFLAG = 'Y' AND VAL.SFLAG = 'Y' AND
       VAL.EMPRECSTS = 'DEP' AND VAL.EMPNO IS NOT NULL and
       dt.RECDATE = val.RECDATE AND DT.SFLAG IS NOT NULL AND
       DT.SFLAG in ('F')
GROUP BY DT.RECPAIDDATE, DT.EMPNO))
GROUP BY RECDATE, EMPNO)
/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the statement, but if I had to guess, I put my money on the expression:

```
RECDATE >'01-Apr-2011'
```

assuming the column `RECDATE` is actually of type `DATE`. Therefor Oracle tries to convert the character value `'01-Apr-2011'`  to a DATE as well. As you did not specify an format mask for this, the default NLS settings are used. If they define a number for the month then the above value would fail conversion.

You should **never** rely on implicit data type conversion. *Especially* not with dates. Use an ANSI literal instead:

```
RECDATE > DATE '2011-04-01'
```

or use the to_date() function with a format mask:

```
RECDATE > to_date('01-Apr-2011', 'dd-mon-yyyy')
```

Note that this could still fail for certain settings of NLS_LANG. In French you would need to specify 'Avr' instead of 'Apr'. So unless you are absolutely certain you can control all NLS_XXX settings all the time I'd strongly suggest to use month numbers instead. If you are more comfortable using to_date() than ANSI literals, you can use:

```
RECDATE > to_date('01-04-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

**Edit**

if it's not the date column you need to check any other column for implicit data conversions.

These expression:

```
sum(round(NVL(trim(DT.EMO), 0)))
round(NVL(trim(EMOLUMENTS), 0))
round(NVL(trim(DT.EMO), 0))
round(NVL(trim(DT.EPF), 0))
```

look suspicious. If the columns in there are real numbers, then `trim()` is invalid and useless. If those are not numbers they could cause that error depending on the content of the column.

This expression `to_number(SUM(CPFEMO))` is also useless as sum() will already return a number there is no reason to call to_number on a number(). Although I doubt it could raise your error you should still avoid it as it does not make any sense.

Comment: I changed/modified TO_DATE INSTEAD OF '01-Apr-2011'.But i got same error.Is there any possiblity in characterset.One system having US7ASCII and anothere system having WE8ISO8859P1.So is there any issue with this character set.